# QGIS - clip buffered areas based on field value

Tags: qgis, buffer, overlapping-features, differences

I have several irregular, adjacent polygons which I first need to buffer, and then remove overlapping areas based on a field value.

This is where I start: irregular polygons with the relevant field value displayed.
[image]

Buffering the polygons lead to this outcome, including the overlap (which needs to be removed).
[image]

This should be the final output - the buffer of the polygon with the lower field value gets "precedence" over the buffer of the polygon with the higher field value.
[image]

Example data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfu37uqvln9z2e5/buffer-clip.gpkg?dl=0).

Sometimes there may be three or more adjacent polygons or overlapping buffers.

I could do this manually, since it's probably a one-time thing, but that wouldn't be elegant and somewhat tedious.

I could buffer each polygon on its own, then run `difference` in the correct order on the polygons, and then merge the results - but again, that's rather time consuming. Does somebody have an idea how to achieve the desired permanent non-virtual output?

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your of data with us?

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfu37uqvln9z2e5/buffer-clip.gpkg?dl=0) @Taras

Comment: I do not really understand your problem :) What is actually your desired output in sense of geometry: can you please show each feature separately? After buffering I got this output: https://imgur.com/a/paPgSgH, look as one you want, is not it? By the way how shall I threat the `"order"`-field, what does it mean 5.5 and 5.8?

Comment: I tried to show the issue in the second image: There is an overlap between both buffer areas - which I need to remove, and only the buffer area with the lower order should be left @Taras

Comment: What is the lower order? 5.5 is lower than 5.8 or vice versa?

Comment: 5.5 is lower than 5.8 - and I tried my best to describe everything as obvious and simple as possible ^^ sorry

Comment: Maybe SAGA's Self-Intersection can help you :)

Comment: @Taras no, not really. Now there are three polygons, instead of two. Sure, I could manually merge the two which should belong together, but... I am lazy/efficient.

Comment: As my boss once said: "laziness forces the progress" :)

Comment: I totally agree with your boss @Taras